# Mysql Inner Join y Count utilizando múltiples tablas

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Tengo 4 tablas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que quiero lograr es solo utilizar una query que permita

- obtener la cantidad de proyectos por usuario.
- obtener la cantidad de usuarios por proyecto.
- obtener la cantidad dependiendo del estado de la tabla issue por proyecto.

Por ahora solo estoy ejecutando múltiples consultas para obtener el resultado de cada uno.

SELECT CANTIDAD DE PROYECTOS POR USUARIO

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, p.image_url, p.created_at, u.id, COUNT(*) AS 'CantidadProyectoUsuario'
FROM project_user pu
INNER JOIN users u ON pu.id_user = u.id
INNER JOIN project p ON pu.id_project = p.id
where pu.id_user = 1
ORDER BY CantidadProyectoUsuario
```

SELECT POR CANTIDAD DE USUARIOS POR PROYECTO

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, p.image_url, p.created_at, u.id, COUNT(*) AS 'CantidadUsuariosProyecto'
FROM project_user pu
INNER JOIN users u ON pu.id_user = u.id
INNER JOIN project p ON pu.id_project = p.id
where pu.id_project = 1
ORDER BY CantidadUsuariosProyecto
```

SELECT POR CANTIDAD DE ISSUES

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, p.image_url, p.created_at, u.id, COUNT(*) AS 'CantidadIssues'
FROM issue u
INNER JOIN project p ON u.id_project = p.id
WHERE u.status = ''
ORDER BY CantidadIssues
```

EL RESULTADO QUE ESPERO OBTENER

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se agradecería muchísimo su ayuda, no importa la forma que se logre obtener el resultado, espero su pronta ayuda.

Comment: Se podría hacer mediante ```SELECT``` anidados dentro de otro ```SELECT``` la estructura podría ser algo parecido a ```SELECT columna_id WHERE columna_id IN (SELECT COUNT(columna_datos) WHERE columna_id=columna_id_2)```

Comment: Podrias mostrarnos como son los selects? con eso uniendolos como subselects se solucionaria...

Comment: @matahombres eso no funciona porque el in no puede ser de un count, daria cualquier cosa

Comment: @gbianchi pero tu haces un ```WHERE``` que checkea si el id de la 1º tabla es de la 2º tabla. Corrígeme si me equivoco...

Comment: Tu where se esta fijando si columna_id esta en la coleccion de el count (la cuenta de registros) donde columna_id = columna_id_2 que ni siquiera se de donde sale. No, es cualquier cosa. @matahombres

Comment: Pues columna_id es el id de la primera tabla y columna_id_2 es el id del select anidado. Creo que eso se puede hacer

Comment: @matahombres no. no podes igualar un count a un id. no tiene nada que ver.. el count te va a dar una cantidad de registros, y el id puede ser un numero tan grande como 50000000... no se puede igualar peras con manzanas, son cosas distintas.

Comment: Vale, ya entendí lo que quieres hacer, cierto es :S

Comment: @gbianchi agregue los selects sugeridos.... espero una pronta ayuda, gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa union all

```
SELECT t.id, t.name, t.image_url, t.created_at, t.uid uid, sum(t.CPU) as CPU, sum(t.CUP) as CUP, sum(t.CI) as CI
FROM (
         SELECT p.id, p.name, p.image_url, p.created_at, u.id as uid, COUNT(*) AS CPU, 0 AS CUP, 0 AS CI
         FROM project_user pu
                  INNER JOIN users u ON pu.id_user = u.id
                  INNER JOIN project p ON pu.id_project = p.id
         where pu.id_user = 1

         UNION ALL
         SELECT p.id, p.name, p.image_url, p.created_at, u.id as uid, 0 AS CPU, COUNT(*) AS CUP, 0 AS CI
         FROM project_user pu
             INNER JOIN users u
         ON pu.id_user = u.id
             INNER JOIN project p ON pu.id_project = p.id
         where pu.id_project = 1

         UNION ALL
         SELECT p.id, p.name, p.image_url, p.created_at, u.id as uid, 0 AS CPU, 0 AS CUP, COUNT(*) AS CI
         FROM issue u
             INNER JOIN project p
         ON u.id_project = p.id
         WHERE u.status = ''

     ) AS t
```

Los subquerys son muy lentos y una mala forma de implementar.

Comment: Por qué son una mala forma? En que te basas?

Comment: ME SALE ESTE ERROR                                                                 
#1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'UNION ALL
         SELECT p.id, p.name, p.image_url, p.created_at, u.id as uid,' en la linea 9

Comment: hay que eliminar el order by en los union all, ya los quite.

Comment: ESTE ES EL SIGUIENTE ERROR AMIGO: #1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca '*) AS CUP, 0 AS CI
         FROM project_user pu
             INNER JOIN users' en la linea 10

Comment: los subselect con un volumen alto de datos hacen lentas las consultas.

Comment: count(*) esto reescribe esta llevando un caracter ASCII

Comment: ahi te deberia funcionar

Comment: Correcto muchas gracias @oegpyg.

Comment: ¿Una pregunta, si deseo que me liste todos los proyectos sin necesidad de enumerarlo?

Answer (score 0):

Intenta utilizando subconsultas, aquí un ejemplo:

```
select count(*) as cant_proyectos, (
 select count(*) as cant_usuarios from project_user where id_project = pu.id
),
(
 select count(*) as cant_issues from issue i inner join project p on i.id_project = 
 p.id where i.status = '' and p.id = pu.id
) from project_user pu where id_user = 1 group by (pu.id)
```

Comment: Por favor considera añadir una explicación a tu código, pues responder solo con scripts se considera de baja calidad

Comment: @Aprendiz creo que lo tienes claro lo que dicen "No solo copies y pegues"

Comment: Por favor lee [answer], explicar tu aporte ayudará a quién pregunto y a futuros usuarios a comprender por qué tú aporte soluciona el problema expuesto